# Bootstrap Carousel Slider Doesn't Transition How I Want In Mobile View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel, responsive-slides

I've added a carousel slider to my website http://www.joekonst.com.

It looks fine apart from when I view it on my IPhone. When the slide transitions over it kind of flashes white on the left hand side when the slides change.

The funny thing is when I view my browser size to the smallest size possible it looks fine, but when I actually view it on my mobile device it looks wrong!

Any ideas?

Thanks Joe :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tech Enthusiast!</title>
    <link href="JoeKonst/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="JoeKonst/mystyles/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JoeKonst/mystyles/css/animate.css" media="screen">
    </head>
  <body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="JoeKonst/blog/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="JoeKonst/archives/archives.html">Archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="5000">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
   <img src="JoeKonst/images/Coding1.png" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
     </div>
 <div class="item">
 <img src="JoeKonst/images/Coding1.png" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="item">
 <img src="JoeKonst/images/Coding1.png" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <h2>A Tech N00bs Guide To Self Development</h2>
<p>Welcome!</p>
<p>My name's Joe Consterdine and I'm currently on a journey trying to improve myself in areas I'm passionate about.</p>
<p>The purpose of this site to hopefully inspire other people in their own self-development journey.</p>
<p>I am no expert, just a guy wanting to learn on a daily basis and spend my time doing things I enjoy. After all, isn't that what lifes about?!</p>
<p>Everything I write in my blog will be based purely on my own experiences. I hope that provides you with some value and helps you on your own journey :)</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <hr>

  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <h2>Web Design</h2>
<p>I started learning Web Design in June 2014. I'd always been interested in web related ventures and after talking with a
friend and fellow designer decided to try it out.</p>
<p>I instantly took a liking to coding and was excited to see some of the sites other designers had produced.</p>
<p>At that particular time I'd been trying out some Internet Marketing activities such as affiliate marketing and list building.</p>
<p>I'd also been learning and testing out local SEO and making whiteboard animation videos at <a href="http://www.Fiverr.com">Fiverr.</a></p>
<p>In the end I decided if I was going to reach a high level in any of these activities I'd have to put a lot of hours in.</p>
<p>I decided to simply stick to learning Web Design and commit fully to mastering it and as it turns out that's been a good decision :)</p>
<p>Fast forward 8/9 months on and I have skills in HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, Bootstrap and Responsive Design.</p>
<p>If you want to know how I've learned everything I have to date in a such a small time period then check out my <a href="JoeKonst/blog/blog.html">Blog</a> which
covers it in more detail.</p>
 </div>
 </div>


 <hr>

  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <h3>Self Development</h3>
<p>This is what the sites all about!</p>
<p>As I touched on before, I'm by no means an expert but hopefully the journey I go on can help you grow in your own.</p>
<p>You might not necessarily enjoy tech related projects like me, but may share the common feeling and need to improve yourself.</p>
<p>If that's the case I'm glad to share my journey with you and hope it provides you with the push you need if you're struggling, or
a reminder that what you're working towards is worthwhile :)</p>
<p>I hope you enjoy your visit on the site and thanks for taking the time to check out my road to glory!</p>
<p><p>Here's the link to my <a href="JoeKonst/blog/blog.html">Blog.</a></p>
<p>I'm updating my content regularly so keep checking it out for updates!</p>
 </div>
 </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="footer">Joe Consterdine 2015&copy;</p>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JoeKonst/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JoeKonst/mystyles/js/js.js"></script>
    <script src="JoeKonst/mystyles/js/wow.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, try to add a background color to your "myCarousel" div (red color for example). When doing the transition, do you see a red line?

Comment: Hey, yeah I see a red line!...so it's just a case of adding a background color that matches your image on your slider? 

And if the images have different background colors then add a few classes with new colors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--To run this file you need to include normal bootstarp file i.e. css and js only--->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="" >
        <title>Responsive Slider Product</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">-->
    </head><!--/head-->
<style>

.demo_chckbox li
{
    float:left;
    width:22%;
    list-style: none;
}
.demo_chckbox
{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.append_demo
{
    width:50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 350px;


}

.append_demo .col-xs-4
{
    width:100%; 
}
.append_demo
{
    display: none;
}
.btn-group
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.reder
{
    color: #FF0505;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .append_demo
    {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mobi-hide
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .append_demo > .btn
    {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .append_demo .col-xs-4
    {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .ads-list
    {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}


</style>

    <body>

        <section id="stories">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Convert Prodcut Slider Into Mobile View</h2>
                <p>Go to Responsive view and check slider (Press F12 and go to Responsive Design Modal and Check)</p> 
                <p class="reder"><strong>Note:</strong>Please refresh page when you are in mobile view.</p>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-9 stories-list">

                                <h2>Popular Product</h2>

                                <div class="btn-group mobi-hide">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="clear-fix"></div>              

                        <div id="scroller" class="carousel slide">
                            <div class="carousel-inner slider_demo">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <h4>Slide-1</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                            
                                         <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                  <h4>Slide-2</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                           
                                       <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <h4>Slide-3</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div><!--/.row-->
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                         <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <h4>Slide-4</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                          
                                         <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <h4>Slide-5</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                            
                                         <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <h4>Slide-6</h4>
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!--append div use for mobile view it is see on the mobile view only-->
                        <div class="append_demo" >
                         <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller_mobi" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller_mobi" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                           <div id="scroller_mobi" class="carousel slide">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">


                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                          <!-- end append div use for mobile view it is see on the mobile view only-->

    <div class="clear-fix"></div>                 


                    </div>

                     <div class="col-md-3 ads-list">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                       <div class="evnet-s">
                            <h3>Mobile View Slider</h3>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller2" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller2" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="scroller2" class="carousel slide">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                          <div class="">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                                   <div class="item ">
                                          <div class="">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                                   <div class="item ">
                                          <div class="">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                                   <div class="item ">
                                          <div class="">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                </div><!--/.item-->
                                   <div class="item">
                                          <div class="">
                                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                <div class="item-inner">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="shop-placeholder.png" alt="">
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                </div><!--/.item-->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>


                     </div>

                </div><!--/.row-->
            </div>
        </section><!--/#recent-works-->






    <!-- forget end-->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var widnowWidth = $(window).width();
    //alert(widnowWidth);
    if (widnowWidth <=768){
        /* convert product slider into mobile slider */
         $(".slider_demo .col-xs-4").appendTo(".append_demo .carousel-inner");
         $(".append_demo .col-xs-4").addClass("item");
         $(".append_demo .col-xs-4:first-child").addClass("active");
    }

    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use this code and run your browser....In above code you see  .append_demo div....i am using append method of jquery to covert product slider into mobile view..Run and Check..append method reduce our code....

Answer (score 0):

Remove "navbar-inverse" class. It will work like a charm ;)